# Compiling Qt3D without Qt source code

Tags: compilation, qt4, qt3d

I'm experiencing difficulties with Qt3D. I can't manage to compile it from source code. If possible, I  would like to compile Qt3D without compiling Qt itself. Can it link against an already compiled Qt ?

- OS: Linux Ubuntu 11.10 (oneiric) x86_64
- Qt version: 4.7.4
- make output:

  cp: cannot create regular file `/usr/include/qt4/Qt3D/qt3dglobal.h': No such file or directory
  make[2]: *** [/usr/include/qt4/Qt3D/qt3dglobal.h] Error 1
  make[1]: *** [sub-threed-make_default-ordered] Error 2
  make: *** [sub-src-make_default-ordered] Error 2
   global/qt3dglobal.h /usr/include/qt4/Qt3D/qt3dglobal.h
  make[2]: Leaving directory`/home/soroush/programs/programming/libraries/qt3d-1.0-src/src/threed'
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/soroush/programs/programming/libraries/qt3d-1.0-src/src'

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to create the `/usr/include/qt4/Qt3D` folder.

Just type this in a terminal window

```
sudo mkdir /usr/include/qt4/Qt3D
```

This fixed the problem for me.

Also you might need to type

```
sudo mkdir /usr/include/qt4/QtQuick3D
```

To create the `QtQuick3D` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `qt-devel` (or similar) development package installed for Qt. The library-only default package doesn't have headers nor development tools (moc, uic, qmake, etc.).

Alas, your problem seems to be that you're trying to install it to the default prefix `/usr` without running `sudo make install`. I suggest you `mkdir ~/qt3d && configure --prefix=~/qt3d`, so that it gets installed in your home directory.